# Does charged Li-on battery burn more than discharged one if damaged?

Tags: physical-chemistry, batteries, electrochemistry

I am wandering if a charged Li-on battery burns more than discharged one if damaged, considering that the charged one has more energy in it. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Possibly one for [electronics.se] but note that "burn more" is very vague.  Does that mean burn longer or burn at a higher peak temperature or burn at a higher average temperature or indeed burn faster (i.e. burn out quicker) or something else ?

Comment: It's not likely. In a $\text{Li}$ ion battery there's solvent, usually a carbonate-type carbonate solvent, which is highly flammable. The amount of sovent however does not depend on the state of discharge of the battery.